# Two manifolds $X$ and $Y$ with two bijective continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ and $Y$ to $X$, but not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

I happen to found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059099/question-about-bijective-functions-and-homeomorphism) about finding two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that there exists bijective continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$, and $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic. I could not produce my own example, and I think the reason is that I am thinking of manifolds only.

Suppose we have two second-countable Hausdorff metrisable manifolds $X$ and $Y$ such that there exists bijective continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$. Can we show that the two manifolds are homeomorphic? Or is there still a counterexample?

Please note that I have taken only one course on metric space and topology, and I don't have much experience with manifolds. So please explain answers in details or post references to the details.

**Edit:** In case of any ambiguity, I would like to state that I do not restrict attention to manifolds without boundary, i.e. the manifolds may have boundary, if such a counterexample exists.

Comment: A [continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism). So you need to assume $X$ and $Y$ are noncompact.

Comment: Hint: Use the invariance of domain theorem.

Comment: If you allow only one of them to have boundary, then you have an easy counerexample: $[0,1]$ vs $\mathbb{R}$. There is also a small article by Laackman which investigates which categories have the Schroeder-Bernstein property. It briefly mentions some examples of manifolds towards the end:        http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Laackman.pdf

Comment: @treedetective There is no continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$ or else $\Bbb R$ would have to be compact.

Comment: That's true. I thought it was just one to one and continuous, but it is also onto... My SB property comment looks out of place now.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this answer you should know about how one can obtain a torus or a cylinder via a projection from the unit square.
To do this, one simply identifies opposite sides of the square: 2 for the cylinder, and 4 for the torus. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus_from_rectangle.gif) there is a nice gif which illustrates this.

Now for the answer. Denote by $R$ the half open unit rectangle, by $C$ the corresponding half open cylinder, and by $T$ the torus. One has projections
$$
\pi_{R, C} : R \to C, \quad \pi_{C, T} : C \to T, \quad \pi_{R, T} = \pi_{C,T} \circ \pi_{R, C} : R \to T
$$

The spaces we need, are the following
$$
X = \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup~ C ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T\\
Y= \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup R ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T
$$
The maps are the following:
From $X$ to $Y$, you project to the right, i.e. $C$ maps to $T$, and then you continue, by mapping the remaining $T$ components to themselves, and the $R$ to themselves as well:
$$
X = \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup~ C ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T\\
~~\downarrow~~~~ \searrow \quad \searrow ~~~\downarrow\\
Y= \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup R ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T
$$
From $Y$ to $X$ you just project upward, i.e. the middle $R$ projects to the single $C$, and the rest is just identities.
$$
X = \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup~ C ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T\\
~~\uparrow~~~~~~ \uparrow ~~~~~~~~~\uparrow\\
Y= \amalg_{\mathbb{N}}R ~\cup R ~\cup~ \amalg_{\mathbb{N}} T
$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic (left as an exercise), this would be a counterexample.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: why are these maps bijective? Neither $\pi_{C,T}$ nor $\pi_{R,C}$ are injective, and as far as I understand, you use both of them in your piecewise definition.

Comment: Neither map is injective... Nice idea, though.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud fixed this. Forgot to add the half open property

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I forgot to mention that the intervalls should be half open