# Invariants to distinguish between non-homeomorphic spaces $X, Y$ where there exist opposing bijective continuous maps $f: X\leftrightarrows Y: g$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I've learnt about the harsh reality that the existence of opposing bijective continuous maps $f: X\leftrightarrows Y: g$ doesn't imply that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic. For this post, let's just call topological spaces $X, Y$ "weakly homeomorphic" if there exist continuous bijection $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$ (without requiring $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ to be continuous).

Suppose $X,Y$ are weakly homeomorphic and path connected. I am unconvinced that the fundamental groups $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(Y)$ are necessarily isomorphic. How would I show this?

Comment: Given we have an answerer slightly missing the point of the question, I did a little bit of a re-wording. I also focused the post on the question about fundamental groups, otherwise this question would be too broad. Feel free to roll back the changes if you prefer the old version.

Comment: I know $X$ can't be compact hausdorff.  But how about an actual example or two?

Comment: @Cpc Isn't it that $X$ can't be compact or $Y$ can't be Hausdorff?

Comment: I think you're right.   Thanks.  @CharlesHudgins

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, misread the answer. My mistake.

Comment: And, yes, there are examples with non-isomorphic fundamental groups, even among, say, (infinite) 2-dimensional simplicial complexes.

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a minor modification of an example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052475/two-manifolds-x-and-y-with-two-bijective-continuous-functions-from-x-to-y).

Let $X'$ be the disjoint union of countably infinitely many 2-dimensional tori $T_n, n\ge 1$, countably infinitely many rectangles
$R_n=(0,1]\times (0,1], n\ge 1$, and a single cylinder $C=(0,1]\times S^1$. Similarly, let $Y'$  be the disjoint union of countably infinitely many 2-dimensional tori $T_n, n\ge 1$ and countably infinitely many rectangles
$R_n=(0,1]\times (0,1], n\ge 0$. For each $n$ fix a base-point $t_n\in T_n$, $c\in int(C)= (0,1)\times S^1$ and $r_n\in (0,1)\times (0,1)=int(R_n)$. There exist continuous bijections
$$
f_0: (R_0,r_0)\to (C, c), g_0: (C,c)\to (T_1,t_1).
$$
These maps extend to continuous bijections $f': Y'\to X', g': X'\to Y'$, which restrict to homeomorphisms
$$
Y' \setminus R_0\to X'\setminus C, X'\setminus C\to Y' \setminus R_0, 
$$
sending base-points to base-points.  Lastly, form the wedge-sum $X$ of $X'$, by identifying all the base-points in $X'$ and also
the wedge-sum $Y$ of $Y'$, by identifying all the base-points in $Y'$. The continuous bijections $f', g'$ descend to continuous bijections $f: Y\to X, g: X\to Y$.

By the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to the free product of the groups $\pi_1(T_n)\cong {\mathbb Z}^2, n\ge 1$, and the cyclic group $\pi_1(C)\cong {\mathbb Z}$.  Similarly, $\pi_1(Y)$ is isomorphic to the free product of the groups $\pi_1(T_n)\cong {\mathbb Z}^2, n\ge 1$. Thus, $\pi_1(X)$ is not isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y)$ since the former contains the infinite cyclic group as a free factor and the second does not. (Cf. Exercise 22 on page 250 in "Combinatorial Group Theory" by Magnus, Karrass  and Solitar.) Hence, we obtain an example of two spaces which are weakly homeomorphic but have non-isomorphic fundamental groups.